# Set value of combobox with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, shapes

I have a combo box that contains 200+ values from a named range and the user can choose to *either* choose any of these 200+ values *or* freely type in any other value into the combo box. This works fine.

My problem is that I am unable to fill in the same combo box with a value specified in a string variable in my VBA code. I want to do the following:

```
Sub FillInComboBox()
Dim strExample as String

strExample = "Random Text"

Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("ComboBox1").Value = strExample 

End Sub
```

I get the "Run-time error '438: Object doesn't support this property or method". 
I have also tried a lot of variations of the code above and I have googled for two hours without success, so I now turn to you as my last hope to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Use following sub.

```
    Sub FillInComboBox()
    Dim strExample As String
        strExample = "Random Text"

        With Sheet1.ComboBox1
            .AddItem strExample
            .AddItem "Second Item"
            .AddItem "Third Item"
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can remove `Second Item, Third Item` if do not need more that 1 item.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value = strExample
```

Comment: It is for form control ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using an ActiveX `ComboBox`. There are a couple ways to accomplish what you want.

1. Set the `LinkedCell` property of the ComboBox to your desired
   location (even on a hidden worksheet).

   - You can read the value of the combobox from that cell, even manually entered text
     `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("ComboBox1").LinkedCell = "C1"`
   - You can set the value of the cell and it will be reflected in the combobox
     `boxValue = Range("C1")`
     `Range("C1") = "custom entry"`
2. Access the ActiveX control ***object*** directly.

   - I emphasized "object" because the control is a child object of the worksheet object. So you can do this:
     `msgbox Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value`
     and it gets you the value directly. Remember to use the name of the control you set in the `Name` property of the control.
   - Setting the value works the same way:
     `Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value = strExample`

Either way will gain access to the control data.